# First time login problem

Tags: login

Have just installed Ubuntu on an HP laptop that has been running Visa, everything went well but I am unable to log in!! Password is not accepted, I have reinstalled several times. Any ideas please?.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your keyboard layout system wide is inconsistent then the one you used when you installed.
Try installing Ubuntu with auto login available and check to see if your keyboard layout is consistent with your countries language.